# How to find a text field is existing in a MYSQL table

Tags: php, mysql

I want to store user **Search Queries** in to MYSQL databse.
I have created a **Search_Queries** field in mysql table and it type is **text**, Collation is **utf8_general_ci**.

If the search word is exists in the table, then update the **Search_Count++**
else
**insert** the search word into the table

I have used for find existing

```
**SELECT ID FROM search_details WHERE Search_Query='keyword' LIMIT 1**
```

if it return empty then insert the keyword

```
**INSERT INTO search_details SET Search_Query='".$SearchQuery."',Search_Count=1"**
```

else update the search_count field

```
UPDATE search_details SET Search_Count='".$Search_Count."' WHERE ID='".$ID."'
```

my problem is if the Search Query is not exists in the table

```
**SELECT ID FROM search_details WHERE Search_Query='keyword' LIMIT 1**
```

this returns with last row instead of NULL

Comment: can you place the whole code which is performing these checks and queries?

Answer (score -1):

successfully insert the Search Query into the table and search count set as to 2

basically , isnt that what you wanted to do in here

```
INSERT INTO search_details SET Search_Query='".$SearchQuery."',Search_Count=1"
```